# Postgres - split tables on 2 different file systems

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 11. Have 3xSSD raid dedicated for DB only, and another (HDD) volume for OS

Problem is that DB size increases much more faster then I assumed - and very shortly it will use entire SSD's space :(

Of course easiest option will be to buy bigger size SDDs and expand array
However (good) SDDs are still quite expensive.

So Im just thinking if Postgres allows split table on 2 different file systems

So I can leave e.g. this year data on SSD volume (for quick access), but move older data to different one - plates HDDs (can be slower), which are not so costly

Ideally this table should be seen still for queries as 'single' table  (so I can query full data range)

Is this possible with Postgres?

Comment: You will need to partition the table by a timestamp, then you can move partitions to different tablespaces.

Comment: Is this fully supported / stable works on 11 ?  Or should look more on 12 ?
I heard there were some issues with that in older versions.
Have You / Anyone been using this in (bigger) PROD implementaiotns  ?

Comment: It's never a bad idea to upgrade to the latest version, but yes that's fully supported and stable in version 11

Comment: Im always trying to keep my systems u2date but 12. is still relatively new (released in Oct if remember well). I have quite sensitive app based on pgsql DB so Im a bit scared to jump from version to version not being stable for 1yr+  ...

Comment: Postgres releases a new major version once a year. v13 is already in beta